# What to do if user closes page in the middle of a mysql long query?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

What happens to the mysql query if the user just closes the page?  Should I be doing any kind of checking for this?  I'm using JPA 2.0(EclipseLink 2.0), JSF 2.0, EJB 3.1(lite) and Glassfish 3.1.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the database, the query will continue to run until completion.  It's possible to kill the session running the query, but there's a security concern with providing that ability outside of the database.

Answer (score 2):

Generally there's nothing you can do to detect it or abort a query in progress.  You're stuck with using up the CPU time to finish the process because there's no way to interrupt a query in progress from Java.

Why would this be an issue?  What is it that you're trying to avoid?

Answer (score 2):

In JPA you can define a timeout which is passed to JDBC.  You can also set a maxResults to limit the number of rows returned.

JDBC now also provides a cancel() API, but JPA does not yet expose this.

Comment: FWIW JDO also provides a cancel() API, and also allows for queries (and their results) to be closed manually.