# Kill long running transactions in JBOSS

Tags: java, sql, performance, jdbc, jboss

We are using Jboss as middle tier in our application and MS Sql server as database and accessing the Sql server through JDBC driver.

Our application modules are designed in the following pattern.

Servlet -> bean -> DB

Now problem is, we have some reports which is running for more than an hour and we couldn't identify those long running queries(transaction) from Jboss perspective.Is there any way by which i can identify SPID of such long running query or stop the query execution from JBoss

Answer (score 0):

You should configure transaction timeout and the long transaction will be killed automatically. Take  a look on this discussion: https://community.jboss.org/thread/27206?tstart=0

or google "how to set transaction timeout in JBoss"

Comment: AlexR, thanks for your answers. Jboss transaction will get terminated if i set txn timeout in JBoss. But still the query will be running in the SQL server. I want to kill that running query. Is there any way to get SPID of running query form Jboss?

Comment: Take a look on this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051277/how-to-kill-db-transaction-that-timed-out-from-jboss Hopefully it can help you.